# Bug with navbar in chrome (UI-Bootstrap)

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I create my landing using anglular and bootstrap. In the above privacy directive **ui.bootstrap.tabs**. Everything is fine but there is a small bug in **chrome** with display nav-tabs in-line. DOM for navbar looks next

```
 <div class="landing-navbar hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="LandingNavbarCtrl">
            <div class="navbar-home-ico col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-5">
                <i class="fa fa-home inline cursor" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-bars inline hidden-md hidden-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <div class="col-md-9 middle-tabs">
                    <uib-tabset active="activeJustified" justified="true">
                    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Home" template-url="views/templates/tabTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="1" heading="Solution" template-url="views/templates/tabTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Projects" template-url="views/templates/tabTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="3" heading="Blog" template-url="views/templates/tabTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="4" heading="Services" template-url="views/templates/tabTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="5" heading="Shop" template-url="views/templates/tabTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="6" heading="About" template-url="views/templates/tabTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="7" heading="Contact" template-url="views/templates/tabTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                    </uib-tabset>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12 right-tabs">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <uib-tabset active="activeJustified" justified="true">
                            <uib-tab index="8" heading="fa fa-twitter" template-url="views/templates/socialTabsTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                            <uib-tab index="9" heading="fa fa-facebook" template-url="views/templates/socialTabsTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                            <uib-tab index="10" heading="fa fa-gitlab" template-url="views/templates/socialTabsTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                            <uib-tab index="11" heading="fa fa-vk" template-url="views/templates/socialTabsTemplate.html"></uib-tab>
                        </uib-tabset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-search-ico col-md-1 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-0">
                <i class="fa fa-search pointer" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="setVisibility()"></i>
                <span class="search-input"><input placeholder="Enter your search term..." ng-class="class" /></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i resize browser to sm-screen size and then set it back to normal size(lg) 
it begins to look right.

When open in chrome
[image: When open in chrome]

when open in other browsers (firefox, IE) or after resizing in chrome:

[image: when open in other browsers (firefox, IE) or after resizing in chrome]

please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at [this fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/EeosPBmLtH) we see that everything is in this case, so you should to provide your CSS. But I'm over confident that the trouble is in:

```
.navbar .nav > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* Internet Explorer 7 compatibility */
}
```

Comment: thanks for response.   width: auto;   display: inline; display: inline-block; float: left; solve my problem